# Cordova Android App having issue with API 33 regarding Permission for Notifications

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-permissions

Playstore is now forcing us to upgrade to API 33. But since we use the Cordova diagnostic plugin (https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin), we now have to force user to go to settings screen to allow notifications. Like this.

[Currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbMhk.jpg)

Previously it was able to do just a pop up but seems not available in that plugin anymore.
[Previously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AqZw.jpg)

Any advice for any plugin that have this capability on API 33 with cordova?

We want to Allow Permission without the user having to go inside the system Notification Setting. It should be enabled through a prompt inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/NeoLSN/cordova-plugin-android-permissions

You should be able to check if the permission is allowed

```
 var permissions = cordova.plugins.permissions;
 permissions.checkPermission(permission, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

In case it isn't, you can request the permission

```
 permissions.requestPermission(permission, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: Consoled cordova.plugins.permissions;, the POST_notification is not available, which is needed to insert  permissions.checkPermission(permission, successCallback, errorCallback); in this function as the first variable.

Answer (score 0):

I created a plugin just for this. It will show a permission dialog for Android 13 (API Level 33) and above. Plus it has an extra dialog in which you can explain the rationale behind the request for permission so the user knows why it is necessary. See here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-notifications-permission